# In Silverlight, how do I catch an XamlParseException exception

Tags: silverlight-4.0, try-catch, xamlparseexception

I am running Silverlight 4 with a MVVM framework.  From time to time, but not always, during a detail page load, I get a XamlParseException.  Since it works 99% of the time, I'm pretty sure the xaml page is fine.

Is it possible to do something similar to the following in my code behind page?

```
public DetailView() {
  try {
    InitializeComponent();
  } catch (XamlParseException e) {
    Debugger.Break();
  }
}
```

In other words, how do I catch the XamlParseException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot catch this exception using try-catch when the parsing is being handled by the runtime.

The only way to catch this exception is when you are using XamlReader like in this discussion:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wpf/thread/02679567-1bd3-41d1-bfd1-326f646d95d1

You can try handling it on Application_UnhandledException.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception(v=vs.95).aspx

And some more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189070(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: So, after I add the handler in the App via             UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
; and it is a SL bug which incorrectly returns a parse error, is it possible to retry the page load from the app handler?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Are you sure it's a SL bug?

Comment: You could try signaling some part of your code to retry an operation using an event aggregator for instance. Just a wild idea.

Comment: Agree with Klinger... your application is not in control when one of these errors appears.